# Way to do DNS lookup through SOCKS5 proxy server

Tags: dns, proxy, socks-proxy

SOCKS5 supports UDP and thus DNS lookups. I'm looking for an application, or a command using standard system utilities, to do a single DNS lookup through a SOCKS5 proxy, and not connect to this address. As an example, here's fake `dig` command to demonstrate what I would want to do, if this switch existed:

```
dig --socks5 1.2.3.4:8080 @4.2.2.1 example.com
```

Answers that work on either Linux, Windows or OSX are accepted.

Answer (score 2):

Some time back I needed something similar. I used a package called `DNS-TCP-SOCK-PROXY`, which you can find [on this github page](https://github.com/jtRIPper/dns-tcp-socks-proxy). It is described as follows:

> A simple dns proxy to tunnel DNS requests over a socks proxy (for example, over ssh or Tor). This can come in handy when setting up transparent proxies.
>
> Usage: ./dns-proxy [options]

and lastly:

> The configuration file should contain any of the following options (and ignores lines that begin with '#'):
>
> socks_addr -- socks listener address
>
> socks_port -- socks listener port
>
> listen_addr -- address for the dns proxy to listen on
>
> listen_port -- port for the dns proxy to listen on (most cases 53)
>
> set_user -- username to drop to after binding
>
> set_group -- group to drop to after binding
>
> resolv_conf -- location of resolv.conf file to read from
>
> log_file -- location to log to (should be /dev/null unless debugging).